# How to pass html tags in a string with node.js, express and ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I use Node.js with Express and EJS and
I want to pass html tags in a string to the browser like this:

```
listRequests.forEach(function(key) {
    messages.push("You have a message from <b>" + key.username + "</b>");
});
```

Later in my code:

```
res.render('/wallets', {
              messages     : messages,
              ...
           });
```

And in my html template, I have something like

```
<h2>Messages</h2>
<% messages.forEach(function(message) { %>
<p><%= message %></p>
<% }); %>
```

The problem: the browser displays the text with the tags like `<b>John</b>` instead of **John**

Comment: Split it into two attributes. Text and name. Like this ```{ text: " You have a message from", username: "John"}```. Then just use the two attributes in the template.  <p><%= message.text %> <b><%= message.username %>  </b></p>

Comment: I will have different kind of messages:

Comment: you have a new <a href="linkToMessage">message</a> from <b>user111<b>
You have a <a href="linkToRequest">request</a> to access your wallet
The wallet <a href="linkToWallet">ABC</a> will needs more funds
that's why I would like to construct the text before sending it to the template

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To render raw html with ejs, use `<%- your_var %>`.
In your case:

```
<h2>Messages</h2>
<% messages.forEach(function(message) { %>
<p><%- message %></p>
<% }); %>
```

It's the same to render partial views.. etc.. give it a try